# Retrive data from database to java

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have a problem to view a date that I receive from my database. Let me explain what I'm doing. I have a database where there is a table called rate1 which is formed from a single column  called value which it contains double numbers. My intent is to take all the data in this column, do the average and return it in my java code. I wanto to display the average in a TextView. My problem is that I do not see anything on the TextView. Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong, and if can he give me solutions to my mistakes? Now I add the code:
This is the Average.java:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Average extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView textViewResult;

private ProgressDialog loading;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_average);

    textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);

    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

    String url = Config.DATA_URL.toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(Average.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String response){
    String name="";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        name = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textViewResult.setText("Name:\t"+name);
 }

}
```

This is the Config.java:

```
public class Config {
public static final String DATA_URL = "https://lbstudios.000webhostapp.com/Average.php";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "value";
public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
}
```

And this is Average.php:

```
<?php
  $connect = mysqli_connect("********", "********", "********", "*******");
$response = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT AVG(value) AS average FROM rate1');
$result = array();
if ($response) {

/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response)) {
    $result[] = $row;
}

/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: can you tell til when you can see (log) the correct data? Is the response ok? JSONObject? Any Error-messages?

Comment: **1.** Did the php works ? **2.** Did the URLConnection works ? **3.** Did the parse work. Is there any exception ?

Comment: How ... you recover `value` from the Config but it is named `average` in the SQL. But I am not sure the array will be named `result`. And you could return a simple Json Object instead of an array since `AVG()` will return one line only

Comment: So I'm not sure that the php file works ... I think so ... It doesn't return any error ... Basically I see that it connects, opens the activity and nothing happens on the TextView ... I tried to change like you said but it does not show me anything yet; Could you write me a solution a bit 'clearer please?

Comment: **1.** open the PHP page and see the result ... **2.** If a problem occurs, there is Exception, does should be catch a at least log. **3.** You can log the response or use debugger **4.** The clearer solution would be to teach you how to debug a program, you should tried to look yourself at the JSON, before to post this question. Then, you should have checked if the Response was received by Android. And of course, you should have check the content of the `Response` AND the parse JSON. This is always a good check list to do, this will help you in 99% of you problem ;) And I am out of charac....

Comment: Thanks for the help but I already solved my problem. :)

Comment: To be fair, someone did it for you ;) You've asked this question way to soon without trying to debug anything yourself. This is a bad practice and won't help you at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the a little problem comes up here;

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
```

And

```
JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
```

Let's suppose that the connection is established successfully with the server and `$result` array is returned as response.

In this particular case, the json array returned by the `json_encode` function is not wrapped with the name `result`. Instead they are just wrapped JSON objects connected together.

The possible solution I can come up with is to delete the above lines I mentioned and replace them with;

```
try { 
JSONArray result = new JSONArray(response);
for(int i=0; i<result.length(); i++){
   JSONObject obj = result.getJSONObject(i);
  // Proceed with your logic with each object accordingly.
}
} catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work   Error:(59, 34) error: cannot find symbol method size()

Comment: Oh gosh..Try length();

Comment: ok thanks; it works but show me this in the TextView {"average":"1.2565489"}... now how can i get only the number?

Comment: You want to know how to display a column value in a textview?

Comment: Because I would like the number in a variable

Comment: It would return also useful for other operations

Comment: Then with each JSONObejct you iterate over the array you will do; textview.setText(obj.getString("value");

Comment: I want something like this:

     private void showJSON(String response){
        Double average;

        try {
            JSONArray result = new JSONArray(response);
            for(int i=0; i < result.length(); i++){
                JSONObject obj = result.getJSONObject(i);
                average = textViewResult.setText(obj.getString("value"));
            }
            } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

Comment: i want to get the average and save it in a double variable;

Comment: I don't get why you set text into your TextView. You can immediately do average = obj.getDouble("value");

Comment: Don't mention it! :)